# Storing Strings in a Structure

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
int playerCount,Face;
struct cardData{
    int value;
    char face[100][100];
}card[100];

//Generating Card faces
    for(int i=0;i<playerCount*3; i++)
    {
        Face = ( rand() % 4 + 1 );
        switch(Face)
        {
            case 1:
            card[i].face[i][1] = "Diamonds";
            break;

            case 2:
            card[i].face[i] = 'H';
            break;

            case 3:
            card[i].face[i] = 'S';
            break;

            default:
            card[i].face[i] = 'C';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I store the club faces in the structure member "face" ? Surely this way is not working. Is there any other way to assign strings to the structure member?

This is the error I get "[Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]"

Comment: Use `strcpy()` to copy C-strings. And the `card[i].face[i] = 'H';` should either be `card[i].face[i][0] = 'H';` or `strcpy(card[i].face[i], "H");` and so on (depending on whether you need C-strings or just a single -- I guess the former).

Comment: If the strings are constant, you can represent them with a `const char *` that can be assigned to like you seem to want to. You cannot assign strings into arrays.

Comment: `card[i].face[i][1] = "Diamonds";`...compiler surely told you something, why you chose to ignore that?

Comment: This is what it said. [Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'char' to 'char [100]'

I am new to programming

Comment: That's **not** the only warning you get with a modern compiler! So either you use an ancient compiler or did not enable warnings as strongly recommended. Read [ask] and follow the advice! We are no "guess the problem" site.

Comment: @user7161165 you didn't mention any errors or warnings in your question.

Comment: [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]

Comment: @user7161165 please update your question with all relevant information

Comment: I am using Dev C++ 5.11

Answer (score 0):

Just an advice for you to store string values to the structure. 
**1. Use string copy:**
   strcpy(card[i].face[i], "H");
or 
**2. Use character assinment:**
   card[i].face[i][0] = 'H';
   card[i].face[i][1] = 0;